# Which nosql Architecture is adapted for XML files

Tags: xml, database

I am wondering which type or architecture will be optimal for storing XML files?
MongoDB can be an obvious answer, but I would like to see if there's other alternatives.
I am willing to write the parsing functions, so please don't consider this as a criteria.